# VBA - API call displayed weather in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, api, weather-api

I am trying to show weather in an Excel sheet. I am extracting the JSON data from the API of open-meteo - https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=13.90&longitude=100.53&hourly=relativehumidity_2m,windspeed_180m,temperature_180m

This is my script, but it is not working for some reason.

```vb
Public Sub openWeather()
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Dim responseData As String
    Dim json As Object
    Dim url As String

    url = "https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=13.90&" & _ 
     "longitude=100.53&hourly=relativehumidity_2m,windspeed_180m," & _ 
     "temperature_180m"
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    With xmlhttp
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        responseData = .responseText
    End With
    
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(responseData)
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Dim hourlyData As Object
        Set hourlyData = json("hourly")
        
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To hourlyData.Count
            If Not IsObject(hourlyData(i)("windspeed_180m")) And & _
             TypeName(hourlyData(i)("windspeed_180m")) = "Double" Then
                .Cells(i, 3).Value = CDbl(hourlyData(i ("windspeed_180m"))
            Else
                .Cells(i, 3).Value = ""
            End If
    
            If Not IsObject(hourlyData(i)("temperature_180m")) And  & _
             TypeName(hourlyData(i)("temperature_180m")) = "Double" Then
                .Cells(i, 4).Value = CDbl(hourlyData(i)("temperature_180m"))
            Else
                .Cells(i, 4).Value = ""
            End If
        Next i
    
    End With
End Sub
```

Error:

> Type mismatch
>
> ```vb
> If Not IsObject(hourlyData(i)("windspeed_180m")) And TypeName(hourlyData(i)("windspeed_180m")) = "Double" Then
> ```

The API call is successful. Hope anybody is able to help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You set the variable `json` as object but it must be a dictionary. There are more errors. Every {} term in the JSON is a dictionary, every [] a collection. Collections work like arrays but dynamic. To reach an item of a collection you have to use it's index. So `TypeName(hourlyData(i)("windspeed_180m")) = "Double"` can never match because the type of windspeed_180 is collection, never double. However, the whole checks for objects and types are not necessary. It's also not necessary to write an empty string to a cell.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it works also with object only. But it's more easy to read the code with the more specific dictionary as type. You can read all values like this:

```
Public Sub openWeather()

  Const url As String = "https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=13.90&longitude=100.53&hourly=relativehumidity_2m,windspeed_180m,temperature_180m"
  Dim json As Dictionary
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim dataSet As Long
  Dim currRow As Long
  
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
  currRow = 2
  
  With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .send
    
    If .Status = 200 Then
      Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
      For dataSet = 1 To json("hourly")("time").Count
        ws.Cells(currRow, 1) = Replace(json("hourly")("time")(dataSet), "T", " ") 'timestamp
        ws.Cells(currRow, 2) = json("hourly")("relativehumidity_2m")(dataSet)     'relativehumidity
        ws.Cells(currRow, 3) = json("hourly")("windspeed_180m")(dataSet)          'windspeed
        ws.Cells(currRow, 4) = json("hourly")("temperature_180m")(dataSet)        'temperature
        currRow = currRow + 1
      Next dataSet
    Else
      MsgBox "Page not loaded. HTTP status: " & .Status
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- `Data => Get&Transform => Get Data => From Other Sources => Blank Query`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//define URL
    URL = "https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=13.90&longitude=100.53&hourly=relativehumidity_2m,windspeed_180m,temperature_180m",

//Read from web
// note header to allow for the compressed json used on this site
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(URL, [Headers=[#"Accept-Encoding"="gzip"]]))[hourly],

//Convert to table
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),

//Expand the lists of values
    #"Expand Lists" = Table.FromColumns(
        #"Converted to Table"[Value], #"Converted to Table"[Name]),

//set the data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expand Lists",{{"time", type datetime}, {"relativehumidity_2m", Int64.Type}, {"windspeed_180m", type number}, {"temperature_180m", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

***Partial Results***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```vb
Dim windspeed_180m As Double
If Not IsObject(hourlyData(i)("windspeed_180m")) And TypeName(hourlyData(i)("windspeed_180m")) = "Double" Then
    .Cells(i, 3).Value = CDbl(hourlyData(i)("windspeed_180m"))
Else
    .Cells(i, 3).Value = ""
End If
```